# Why is Jyotisha or Astrology considered to be the eye of the Vedas

Tags: astrology, vedanga

Why is Jyotisha or Astrology considered to be the "Eye of the Vedas"?

Has this phrase come from any of the vedic scriptures? or when was it first used?

I got to know about this phrase from lots of articles from astrological sites ([for example](https://medium.com/@contactbizlist/jyotish-astrology-is-considered-to-be-the-eye-of-the-veda-the-science-which-helps-one-see-the-403c994165bd)) and one can google the phrase "Jyotish eye of the veda" & its commonly used as such.

Comment: In Rig Vedic point of view, I don't think there was such a opinion inserted therein, as it contains spiritual aspects only.. However,  Yajurveda and Atharva Veda May contain as they discuss about physical sacrifice.

Comment: However, mention of astronomy related issues can be found in Rig Veda

Comment: may be they mean to say "light of veda" because the root word of `Jyotish` is Jyoti meaning light.

Answer (score 4):

Astrology (Jyotiṣa) is known as the eye of the Vedas.
The most crucial text in Hindu Astrology - The Brihat Parāśara Horā Śāstra (BPHS) declares it in the very beginning (Ch 1. Verse 2).

> Offering his obeisance’s to all-knowing sage Parasara and with folded hands, Maitreya said: O venerable, **Astrology, the supreme limb of the Vedas**, has three divisions, viz. Hora, Ganita and Samhita. Among the said three divisions, Hora is still far excellent. I desire to know of its glorious aspects from you. Kindly relate them to me. BPHS I.1-3

> भगबन् परमं पुण्यं गुह्यं वेदाङ्गमुत्तमम्।
> त्रिस्कन्धं ज्यौतिषं होरा गणितं संहितेति च॥ २

Here obviously, the supreme limb is the eye.

Another classical Astrological text Praśna Mārga says it even more clearly.

> The Vedas have six limbs, viz. Jyotisha, Kalpa, Nirukta, Siksha, Vyakarana and Chhandas. - Prasna Marga I. 10

> For the Vedas, the six important limbs, viz. the feet, the face, the hands, the eyes, the nose, and the ears, are represented by Chhandas, Vyakarana, Kalpa, Jyotisha, Siksha and Nirukta, respectively. - Prasna Marga I. 11

> **As Astrology is the eye of the Vedas**, it is given the pride of place. No person possessing all the organs intact but without eyesight can have individuality. - Prasna Marga I. 12

References:

1. Brihat Parasara Hora Sastra (Vol. 1) translated by R. Santhanam
2. Prasna Marga (Vol. 1) translated by B. V. Raman