# Is marriage an act of free will or an act of destiny?

Tags: scripture, karma, marriage, destiny, free-will

I would like to understand the point of view of our scriptures on this topic : Is marriage an act of free will or an act of destiny?

If we consider swayamvar of Rama and Sita, it definitely qualifies as an act of destiny, for as we know, Rama was incarnation of Lord Vishnu and Mata Sita was incarnation of his consort, Lakshmi.

But does this mean all marriages are destined primarily based upon our past Karmas and there is no free will?

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of: [Does Prarabdha karma determine one's spouse?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44430/does-prarabdha-karma-determine-ones-spouse)

Comment: Marriages are inevitable. The jiva loses its Shiva shakti tattva at birth in a human body. Thus the union of Shiva Shiva shakti is marriage. Happens externally and also internally.

Comment: @Proxy- Could you please address my question about Venkateshwara Stotra? I'm unable to figure out how to contact you directly on HSE. Thank you.

Comment: I did a lot of research on this question, as my question that Vivikta has linked was also not answered. I did learn through my research that marriage is destined. This conclusion was reached after reading Ramana Maharshi and also questioning some Advaita students I know.

Comment: @curiousseeker I agree with you, as the events unfold in ones life, person will understand that it was not his/her free will, it was destined to happen that way!