# Does our Kuṇḍalī reflect our past lives and the karmas?

Tags: karma, astrology, navagraha, destiny, free-will

Well, most of us are well aware of this very basic doctrine of Karma. *As you sow, so shall you reap.*

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/47943/17833),

Chandrashekhara Bharati Swaminah, who was known to be a *Jīvanmukta*, explains Free-will and fate, as follows:

> Fate is past karma, free-will is present karma. Both are really one,
> that is, karma, though they may differ in the matter of time. There
> can be no conflict when they are really one. Fate, as I told you, is
> the resultant of the past exercise of your free-will. By exercising
> your free-will in the past, you brought on the resultant fate.

My question revolves around the conception of free will in relation to past lives, fate and the Vedic Astrology (jyotiṣa).

Is it explicitly mentioned anywhere that our Kuṇḍalī reflects our past lives, and the karmas committed in those?
More precisely, Is it mentioned anywhere that the planetary arrangements in our Kuṇḍalī are a result of our past karmas?

i.e., the person is necessarily born in a certain planetary arrangements to experience the results of his past karmas.

Or Alternatively, if we go by reverse engineering logic -

Can jyotiṣa-śāstras help in predicting our past lives and the good or bad karmas committed in those lives?

<sup>Note that I'm only looking for scriptural statements that explicitly states what I ask.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

> "Whatever has been acquired by a person through his karma — whether good or bad — done in previous births, the hora now reveals its fruition or effects." - ***Brihat Jataka of Varahamihira I.3***