# Fruits of which types of Karma do we get in this life , in next birth and in heaven/hell?

Tags: karma

1. Fruits of which type of Karma do we get in this life ?
2. Fruits of which type of Karma do we get in next birth ?
3. Fruits of which type of Karma do we get in heaven/hell ?

There are certain types of Karmafal which we get because of our acts of previous lives -[like death](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/50998/is-death-always-part-of-prarabdh)

Is there any classification of Karma from where can know fruits of which karma we get in life , in next birth and in heaven/hell. ?

Answer (score 9):

Scriptures mention about three type of Karmas  1. Sanchita (accumulated) 2. Prararbdha (already ready to bear fruits) and Vartamana (the current ongoing Karmas).

Among these, the fruits of the Prarabdha Karmas are to be experienced while living on earth. The fruits of the Sanchita Karmas are to be experienced in the future, meaning in the afterlife i.e. either in Heaven/Hell or in the next births. Same is true for the deeds that we are currently doing (the Vartamana Karmas). They are like seeds being sown on the ground. Their fruits will have to be experienced by the Jiva possibly in the afterlife (and not in this).

From Devi Bhagavatam's Chapter 21 (Book 4):

> 19-20. Effort, application and manifestation of energy are certainly
> the duties of man; but their effects are all under the Great Destiny
> or Fate. The Pundits knowing the ancient lore say that there are three
> kinds of Karma mentioned in the Purânas and Âgamas :-- First, the
> Sanchita Karma (done in past births); the Prârabdha Karma, the Karma
> already done; and the Vartamân Karma (Karma in hand).
> 21. The Karma, auspicious and inauspicious, done in many previous lives and preserved in seed forms, remains always inherent in a human
> soul. Urged on by this Karma, the Jîvas quitting their previous
> bodies, enjoy Heaven or Hell as effects of these, their own acts.
> 22-23. According to their good or bad works, the Jîvas acquire the
> higher happy body and enjoy various pleasures in the Heavens, or they
> take up very painful vicious bodies and suffer various pains in hell.
> 24-25. At the expiry of the above period in Heaven or Hell, when there
> comes the time of his assuming another body, the Jîva becomes
> conscious of the subtle body (Linga Deha) and takes his birth again.
> When the Linga Deha comes into existence, the part of the Karma done
> in various previous births that are ripe and ready to yield their
> fruits, gets attached to the Jîva by God (or Destiny).
> 26. Therefore the collective effect of Karma done in previous births always exists in a Jîva’s body. O Fair-eyed One! The effects of
> Prârabdha Karma, ripened and ready to yield their fruits must have to
> be experienced by a Jîva, whether happy or unhappy.
>
> 27. O beautiful young woman! Penances, performed according to rules, destroy the effect of Karmas that are in hand and are weak (i.e., not
>     yet accumulated strongly as to remain in seed forms).
> 28. The Prârabdha Karma, those acts out of all the previous acts done in previous births that are fully mature and ready to yield their
>     fruits, cannot be averted; their effects must have to be experienced
>     and then they can die away; they cannot be expiated by penances or any
>     other remedial measures. Therefore you must hand over unconditionally
>     your new born babe unto the hands of Kamsa.

As mentioned in the passage, Sanchita Karmas are the deeds done by the Jiva in the previous births. Among these Karmas, some amount may have become Prarabdha by now. Fruits of those have to be experienced in this life only and those of the remaining part in the afterlife/next births.

Comment: Can you explain me the shloka no. 27 and 28.. Actually I'm not able to understand the terms..like..Karma in Hand , Weak Karma , Fully mature karma,etc. So can you explain what those 2 shlokas (27 and 28) are trying to say?

Comment: 27 is talking about those Sanchita Karmas which are not yet ready to bear fruits (they will do so sometime in the future but not at present). These Karmas can be destroyed if right penances/remedies are performed at present. But 28 is talking about those Prarabdha Karmas which are already starting to bear fruits. These fruits have to be experienced without fail. There is no way for the Jiva to nullify the effects of these Karmas. @ShriRambhakt

Comment: So 27 is talking about sanchita karma which are weak and 28 is talking about prarabdha karma which are ready to bear the fruits? Isn't it?

Comment: Btw is there any way to know about those karmas? I mean , For example we can do penances for nullifying the effects of weak sanchita karma..but how we'll get to know whether that karma is weak or strong , sanchita or prarabdha?

Comment: Yes you are right about understanding 27 and 28. And yes, we have to keep doing penances. But only for those sins which we have committed recently. For sins committed in the past lives the time for performing penances have already elapsed long ago. Possibly those sins have matured and we are already facing their fruits now. @ShriRambhakt

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: Could you please tell other śāstras which talk of various types of karma?

Comment: Need to check that @Bingming

Comment: I already found one, Śiva Purāṇa ([4.23.42-45a](https://archive.org/details/SzWh_shiv-mahapuran-of-veda-vyas-chapter-2-second-half-with-hindi-vyakhya-illustration-gita-press/page/n297/mode/2up?view=theater))

Comment: *O Maheśvarī! In karmakāṇḍa, three types of karman viz. sañcita, kriyamāṇa, & prārabdha, are declared. The karma done in pūrvajanmas are sañcita, and the karma one does bhoga of via their phalas, with śarīra, are prārabdha. The śubha or aśubha karma that's consistently being done in this lifetime, are called kriyamāṇa by paṇḍitas.*
*The nāśa of prārabdha karma happens only by their bhoga and nothing else.*

Comment: Thanks for the find @Bingming