# Where we get punishment/reward for our Karma?

Tags: karma

Which Karma we get punishment-
.

1. In this life
2. In heaven/hell
3. In next birth

Is there any such classification ?

Comment: Duplicate of one of your own questions--https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/51009

Answer (score 0):

Some negative Karma is instant - you rob a bank, you go to jail. Some Karma will appear in next life. There is no heaven or hell.